# Is Ulfric Stormcloak capable of a Dragon Shout?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How *did* Ulfric Stormcloak kill High King Torygg?

Most NPCs including guards keep telling me Ulfric Stormcloak killed High King Torygg by shouting at him. When I came to Solitude, I found that Roggvir is executed because he let Ulfric leave in a fair and square duel according to the rules of the day.

But when I speak with Elisif, she says Ulfric shouted in a voice and her husband was no more.

Many NPCs also say something similar.

I went to High Hrothgar, and found it takes years to master *one* single shout. I can not talk to the others besides Arngeir because their *voice* would kill me instantly.

Is Ulfric capable of Dova/Dragon shouts? If yes then is he also a potential Dragonborn? Or he has just **studied** the Way of the Voice?

If so is there a shout that can disintegrate people like that?

Comment: It should also be noted that he does not appear to use any shouts, like Draugur Deathlords do, in his final battle.

Comment: @Iszi Which final battle? I am with the Imperial, and in final battle in Windhelm he did use the shout.

Comment: @Iszi I've also seen him shouting when leading the Stormcloaks against Solitude. He *does* shout in battle.

Comment: Eh, maybe I dispatched him too quickly then.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ulfric is capable of shouting because he studied with the Greybeards but couldn't stand being away from the events of the war and as such left to join the Empire. He is not Dragonborn though: I think the idea is that almost anyone can learn a shout ***if*** they are super dedicated (since it takes a lot of time for non-Dovahkiin).

He also states that he Fus'd him to the floor and finished him off with a sword.

And no, there isn't a shout available to the Dovahkiin in-game that is powerful enough to disintegrate an enemy. That's not to say there isn't a possibility of one in the world of Skyrim, just that you can't learn it in the game.

Just for reference you can find some more information about Ulfric's past [**here**](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Ulfric_Stormcloak).

**EDIT:** The Dragonborn DLC allows you to get a passive power that adds a chance for Unrelenting Force to disintegrate enemies. Thanks 3ventic! :)

Comment: @desaivv I don't think they trained him as much as he learn't with them, in a sense was once one of them. If you click the link I posted in my answer you can find all this information on the Skyrim Wikia. It says on there that Ulfrik himself tells this story but since I haven't completed the Ulfric/Stormcloak/Legion storyline, I cannot confirm.

Comment: @desaiw they may not have actively trained him, but he certainly lived and studied at High Hrothgar for a substantial period (several years).

Comment: In one of the dialogues for the Stormcloak questline I believe Ulfric says that he stabbed the high king in the heart with a sword rather than an axe - though it could just be a break in continuity in the game script

Comment: The Dragonborn DLC allows you to get a passive power that adds a chance for Unrelenting Force to disintegrate enemies

Comment: Ulfric finished him with a sword, after shouting him down.

Answer (score 16):

All 3 of your questions are answered in dialogue with Ulfric himself. If you go see him before you go to High Hrothgar and before asking him about joining the Stormcloaks, you can ask him about the Greybeards, Dragonborn status, etc.

He tells you that he was chosen as a lad by Arngeir to become a Greybeard but he couldn't dedicate himself to the Way of the Voice that required detachment from people and events in Skyrim. He and Arngeir are estranged over his departure. He studied approx. 10-12 years to learn the 3 words of power for Unrelenting Force. This is the only shout he knows, but even the Masters of the Voice in ancient times before Jurgen Windcaller and the Greybeards (see Forelhorst Journal) only knew the Force shout. All Deathlord Draugr (highlords of the Dragon Cults) know Unrelenting Force.

There is no known shout to disentigrate foes. They can be weakened by "Marked for Death." Theoretically, the dragon word for "disentigrate" would do just that but it is not in game (assuming dragons have a word for that in their language).

Ulfric also relates the Duel with the High King. He is aware of the exaggerated tales of his use of the Voice and admits using Unrelenting Force to throw Torygg "but it was my sword that pierced his heart."

Comment: Ulfric knows many more shouts then Unrelenting force, considering he kept using Disarm and knocking my weapon out of my hand.

Answer (score 6):

To add to the other answers (which are mostly lore-based), gameplay-wise, the [Ulfric Stormcloak NPC](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ulfric_Stormcloak) *is* capable of a dragon shout.

You can notice Ulfric Stormcloak using [Unrelenting Force](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Unrelenting_Force) (Fus Ro Dah) if you fight him in the [Battle for Windhelm](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Battle_for_Windhelm) (part of the Imperial Legion [Civil War questline](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Civil_War)) or if you fight beside him in the [Battle for Solitude](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Battle_for_Solitude) (part of the Stormcloak [Civil War questline](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Civil_War)).

Answer (score 3):

No he is not a dragonborn. He trained for years *because* he is not.

He himself says he Fus'd him to the ground, then killed him with his axe. (If you believe him).

'Fair and square' duel is debatable, but certainly there was no cloak and dagger.

Answer (score 2):

In the latest update, Jarl Ulfric can be seen using the Frost Breath shout in the battle for Solitude. (From update 1.81 onwards)

Comment: And you got that information ... where exactly? Cite your sources, folks.

Comment: @FEichinger I'm not sure what your criticism is. Are you worried something is plagiarized? A google search doesn't indicate it's a copy and paste job. Otherwise, this info seems readily available simply by *playing the game*, so I'm curious about the request for a source.

Comment: @Sterno The note about the particular update is what worries me.

Answer (score 1):

Ulfric actually does shout and can kill you. He did to me when I attacked too soon in the war at the palace (playing an imperial as always). He shouted me across the room. So yes, he can shout and he can and will do it.

I do believe he did it to the high king. He's a tool in my book. Sybille Stentor, the court wizard in solitude tells you that they thought he was going to ask for Torygg's support, which if Ulfric had asked, Torygg would have very likely given or definitely given according to Sybille, but instead, Ulfric abused his shout power and killed Torygg. That conversation alone, if not for all the racist crap from the nords and the fact that they created the forsworn and even were behind the creation of the falmer if you go back that far are reasons I always join imperials. Stormcloak types in the game are terrible. They go after anyone not a nord unless you happen to join them in the game. They destroyed the snow elves which caused the falmer, reason enough to hate them. Snow Elves were a beautiful race. It should be noted however that the Snow elves tried to exterminate humanity because they thought the human settlers were too successful and might one day rival them. Ysgramor fled back to Atmora and returned with the 500 to avenge themselves on the Snow elves that had butchered their kin. See here for more info http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Ysgramor_(Lore)

Answer (score -2):

Yes the Graybeards did train Ulfric, or he at the very least studied with them. To me, that says they trained him. He says this when you ask Ulfric about the rumour that he "shouted the High King to death". He also specifically says something to the effect that his "shout threw him, but it was his blade that pierced his heart".

In summary: Ulfric *himself* says he studied at High Hrothgar for years to learn the ONE shout (*fus... roh dah*!), and that his shout merely stunned/staggered the High King so that his blade could pierce his heart. He did not "shout him to death" or "disintegrate" the king.

Answer (score -3):

Actually yes there is a shout that can disintegrate people instantly and it is unrelenting force, using a black book from Hermaeus Mora and choosing dragonborn force it does more damage and can disintegrate people. I'm not saying Ulfric himself got that ability because most daedric artifacts work differently for different people but maybe he was naturally talented with unrelenting force or maybe he studies about it in his free time to become stronger.

Comment: You're extremely hard to understand, mostly because you skipped most punctuation. But from what I can guess what you want to say, I think you're not answering the question.